# Trying to filter out leaking AC from an alternator with a bad diode

Tags: automotive, bridge-rectifier

So my alternator is leaking excess AC due to a bad diode. It in turn, fried part of my PCM/ECM. Which in turn, prevented my alternator from charging the batteries in my truck and it rendered all my gauges inoperable. (They are all electronically controlled by the PCM.)
So I found an external voltage regulator, wired it in and solved the charging issue.
I had a mini digital DC voltage display, wired that in and fixed the voltmeter issue.
I also had a 12volt digital temperature relay which I wired in and set to alarm at 205 degrees F. I poked a small hole in the overflow tube and then thermally sealed and back fed a thermocouple back to the radiator, then sealed the hole around the leads.
Now I still have the fuel gauge and speedometer to figure out, but before I get to all that, I still have .19 mV AC leaking from the alternator.

I cant afford to replace the diode rectifier in the alternator, (the diodes I have on hand wont really fit into the alternator itself either) nor can I afford to replace the PCM ($1200) for another 3 to 5 weeks and I have to run the vehicle. I don't have much of a choice.
Single Dad of 5 kids, with 2 still at home and putting the other three through college, so I've got mouths to feed. Anyway, I was thinking about possibly adding an inline rectifier. I've got four diodes that could handle the load and capacitance to smooth things out, but that would probably reduce the voltage if I'm doing the math right.
Are there any ideas for possibly filtering out some of the unwanted AC?
I know you cant filter it ALL out as diodes are imperfect but if I could get it down to somewhere in the vicinity of .05mV As opposed to the .19mV that I have now, would prevent other circuits from within the PCM/ECM from shorting out, because if it shorts out the fuel injection pump then I'm completely screwed.

I tried asking in some of the auto forums online, but they didn't offer any solutions except replacing parts, which I cant afford at the moment. They were just too focused on the problem. I prefer to put my time and energy into solutions, I already know what the problem is.
So I'm one of those "There's always a way" kind of guys. Soooo, while I'm waiting for possible advice here, in the meantime, I will continue my search. Any advice, direct orders, recommendations, and or comments would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Replace the diode.  If you don't, it will keep killing parts of your truck and cost you more money.  The right way to "filter out the AC" is with that dead diode you don't want to replace.

Comment: Thats the thing, I cant afford it at the moment.  If I had the money, I wouldnt be asking for alternatives here. I cant replace the bad diode individually without destroying the whole assembly. And the assembly is right around $100. Which I dont have at the moment. Cant afford it until my next check 10 days from now.

Comment: It basically comes down to, do my kids eat or do I fix the truck? I know a hundred might not seem like much and a few years ago i wouldnt even think twice, but money is extremely tight. Right down to every last dollar. Im a single Dad with 5 kids, 2 still at home and I'm on disability with vascular disease.

Comment: Are you sure about those measurements? "0.19mV" (aka 190uV) is literally nothing in an automotive 12V supply, If that's really all you have then there's nothing left to filter.

Comment: JUNK YARD BONE YARD WHATEVER   You don't need buy this new.   Go on EBAY man, lots of auto reclaimers post stuff there.

Comment: The diodes in your alternator are in a big chunk of metal to get rid of the heat.  Any diode you add will also have to handle the heat.

Comment: I still don't understand the problems. You say "I solved the charging issue", so - as I read it - the alternator is running with reduced power because one diode is gone. You have replaced some basic instrument functions with extra hardware, that is working. Sounds like a temporarily working solution. Where and how do you measure these absurd small voltages and why do they bother you? What is not working except the ECM? What hinders you from using the truck?

Comment: "I still have .19 mV AC leaking from the alternator." 19mV AC? That's nothing. Why do you think it's a problem? It's not true that the ECU would need 5mV. Automotive electronics routinely deal with transients and noise much bigger than a fraction of a Volt. Anything less than 1VAC between red and black battery terminals will be completely fine. I've had an almost dead battery on my SUV and the ripple voltage was 3VAC on top of 15VDC when the car was running. Everything still worked except for the entertainment system.

Answer (score 3):

So, one solution would be to disconnect the alternator electrically completely.

Then you would run on battery power only. Probably need two batteries to be safe when winter comes...

Charge the battery used that day overnight and use the other so one each day.

Had to do this sort of thing with farmer's tractors so they could get the crops in when the alternators failed. Often used to fit a smaller drive belt so I could remove the alternator and rebuild it.